# Accidental Messing With chmod

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, permissions, ubuntu-14.04

I just learned the permissions and executability and tried to make some files (if that helps, `/usr/local/bin/idea/bin/idea.sh` and `/usr/local/bin/julia`) executable. Unfortunately, I did something stupid. I typed `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/*` so as you expected, everything, including subfolders and their corresponding files are executable for any user, I tried to reverse what has been done by typing `sudo chmod -x /usr/local/` and try to executable-them separately, but it's like my `cd` is paralyzed.

```
couzhei@couzhei-lappy:~$ cd /usr/local/
bash: cd: /usr/local/: Permission denied
```

I need to add that because of my anger issues, I also typed

```
sudo chmod -R -X  /usr/
```

Now everything is back to the place where there must be only a script and a bash compiler, note that nothing works in almost any directory, `cd, mv, chmod, chown` etc they all are oblivious words to my machine now.  I am perfectly fine with another installation of the OS, but is it possible to access to some of my files and store them to an external hard drive? especially home directory and a place inside `/usr/local/` where I stored in an encrypted file all my passwords!

Thx

** **EDITED**

Nothing seems to be working properly. In the recovery mode, with root access, I typed:

```
cp /usr/local/Passwords.odt /home/couzhei/
```

It echoed this

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/couzhei/Passwords.odt': Read-only file system
```

Comment: You did have a complete back-up BEFORE you started messing around?

Comment: Nope, that was the first time, didn't know that chmod can be that dangerous.

Comment: If you need `sudo` then it can be dangerous.

Comment: Don't play with the root account or with `sudo`. Use your personal account. Create backups of your system.

Comment: So these comments means I should forget about my passwords, right?! @Cyrus

Comment: Connect the disk to a working system or boot from live CD or USB. With working `chmod` regain access to your files. With working `cp` copy them to external drive.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot from a live CD/USB/iso/etc. your filesystem is usually mounted under `/mnt/sysimage` (in RHEL/CentOS) and as read-only. The root filesystem from the live image is on `tmpfs`(stored in RAM) as opposed to non-volatile memory (HDD, SSD, etc.). You need to:

```
1. boot in rescue mode.
2. chroot /mnt/sysimage #(or where your filesystem is mounted by default, depens on distro)
3. mount -o remount,rw / #(remount your filesystem as Read-Write)
4. restore the correct permission for /usr/local/bin
5. exit # to exit the chroot 
6. exit # to reboot
```

Hope this helps.